# No wireless and display issues on Dell Inspiron 1210 (Mini 12)

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-netbook

I recently upgraded a friend's Dell Mini 12 (Inspiron 1210) from Ubuntu 8.10 to 10.04 netbook edition. After installing, and performing the available updates, I'm unable to detect any wireless networks (it knows it has a wireless card, but won't list any active networks).

There also seems to be an issue with the display drivers: when scrolling, resizing, or drawing any windows there is a noticeable lag as I watch the screen redraw. As if there are no compatible display drivers installed.

All these problems go away the moment I boot up a version of 8.10. But I'd like to keep 10.04 if possible.

Are these common problems? Everything I've read suggest this is laptop should be compatible. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Ubuntu wiki page on netbooks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Netbooks#Dell%20Mini%2012%20%28Inspiron%201210%29) the display driver issue is well known. For Lucid [the recommended fix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo/) is to install updated graphics drivers from a PPA.

Per that page execute the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gma500/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install poulsbo-driver-2d poulsbo-driver-3d poulsbo-config
```

then reboot to enable the newly installed drivers.

With wireless, the solution is less well-documented, but it looks like many netbooks have success using the Broadcom STA drivers. These can be enabled by the "Hardware Drivers" application (under the "Administration" menu).

Comment: Fantastic! That solved both problems. My friend will be happy to have her laptop back.

Comment: +1  Thanks a lot, that fixed display issues with my Asus EEE 1201HA